# How do I update the scope of a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my code:

```
angular.module("testApp", [])
   .service("testService", function() {
      var privateScope = [1,2,3];
      return {
         getScope: function() {
           return privateScope;
         },
         addToScope:function(num) {
           privateScope.push(num);
         }
      }
   })
   .controller("testCtrl", ["$scope","testService"], function($scope, testService) {
      $scope.tests = testService.getScope();
      $scope.current = $scope.tests[0];
      $scope.addToScope = testService.addtoScope;
   });
```

The View:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="num in tests">
        <div>{{num}}</div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="addToScope(Math.round(Math.random() * 10))" />
</div>
```

Will clicking on the button update the scope of the controller as well as the service? I'm very confused as to how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it well because the `privateScope` in the service and `$scope.tests` *refer* to the same array.

If you want to keep them separate, then you should return a `copy` of the array from the service.

**Deep copy**

```
     getScope: function() {
       return angular.copy(privateScope);
     }
```

**Shallow copy**

```js
     getScope: function() {
       return privateScope.slice();
     }
```